# kodein - data's value injected are not data's value retrieve

Tags: android, dependency-injection, kotlin, kodein

In my `CallType` class, i put my injected data `connectivityState.callBackState` to true, which is initialized to false in my `ConnectivitySte` class. But in my `IncomingCallBroadcastReceiver` class, my boolean data `callBackState` is not `true` but `false`.

```
class CallType {

val kodein = Kodein {
    bind<ConnectivityState>() with provider { ConnectivityState() }
}

private val connectivityState: ConnectivityState = kodein.instance()

fun call(number: String) {

//!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\\
connectivityState.callBackState = true
}    


class IncomingCallBroadcastReceiver : KodeinBroadcastReceiver() {

   private val connectivityState: ConnectivityState by instance()

   override fun onBroadcastReceived(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
   
   //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  IT'S FALSE HERE WHEREAS I PUT IT TO TRUE IN CALLTYPE CLASS
   if (connectivityState.callBackState) {
    }
}    

class ConnectivityState {
   var iaxState = false    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
bind<ConnectivityState>() with provider { ConnectivityState() }
```

You are binding to a `provider` scope, which means that *a new instance will be returned every time you ask for an instance*.

If you want the same instance to be returned every time, you need to bind to a `singleton`:

```
bind<ConnectivityState>() with singleton { ConnectivityState() }
```